# Animate CC HTML5 easelJS stage.X stage.Y mouse position not consistent between chrome and and firefox

Tags: html, easeljs, animate-cc

I have an application where I need an information card to follow the position of the mouse.

I have used the following code:

```
stage.addEventListener("tick", fl_CustomMouseCursor.bind(this));

function fl_CustomMouseCursor() {

    this.NameTag.x = stage.mouseX;
    this.NameTag.y = stage.mouseY;

}
```

It works perfectly in Firefox but in Chrome and Safari the further away the mouse gets from 0,0 on the canvas the larger the distance between NameTag and the mouse (by a factor of 2).

I look forward to any comments.

Comment: Here is the project live: http://www.norplexbusinesscentre.com/Floorplan-HTML5.html

Answer (score 3):

I see the issue in Chrome as well as Firefox - I don't believe it is a browser issue.

The problem is that the stage itself is being scaled. This means that the coordinates are multiplied by that value. You can get around it by using `globalToLocal` on the stage coordinates, which brings them into the coordinate space of the exportRoot (`this` in your function). I answered a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490701/drag-drop-not-working-properly-on-retina-ipad-createjs/40493428#40493428), which was caused by Animate's responsive layout support.

Here is a modified function:

```
function fl_CustomMouseCursor() {
    var p = this.globalToLocal(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);
    this.NameTag.x = p.x;
    this.NameTag.y = p.y;
}
```

You can also clean up the code using the "stagemousemove" event (which is fired only on mouse move events on the stage), and the `on()` method, which can do function binding for you (among other things):

```
stage.on("stagemousemove", function(event) {
    var p = this.globalToLocal(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);
    this.NameTag.x = p.x;
    this.NameTag.y = p.y;
}, this);
```

Cheers,

Comment: @TimTyler you might wanna select the correct solution as the answer.