# Animate CC "pressmove" issues in Safari 10.0.1

Tags: safari, drag-and-drop, easeljs, animate-cc

Using the easeljs tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrwKAikvims) I created a drag and drop "test" in Animate CC using symbols and "pressmove", "pressup". It works fine in all the browsers (and Ipad) except for Safari on my mac. When starting to move the "draggers" they "jump" to a different location. They also move closer and further from the mouse when dragging.

The test page is located [here](http://www.wallaceinteractive.com/test/dragdrop/olaf_iframe.html):

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure this is the same issue reported here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809123/animate-cc-html5-easeljs-stage-x-stage-y-mouse-position-not-consistent-between-c/40819693#40819693

Comment: Thanks Larry. I looked for hours and didn't see this. I will give it a try. appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks that worked : )

Comment: No worries, it seems to be a common issue now that Adobe has introduced their responsive scaling. We (CreateJS) are looking at solutions in the framework, or at least recommendations to Adobe.