# EaselJS hitTest on moving bitmaps

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

I am trying to implement a game where there are moving objects(Bitmaps) and I need to detect collision. I used the following code to make objects move(transform) and check `hitTest` with mouse hover.

However, the alpha is not changed with the correct mouse position, instead, it detects the left upper corner of the canvas.

[image]

```
rock = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult("rock"));
rock.setTransform(800, 270, 0.5, 0.5);
stage.addChild(rock);
// ..... 

createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF;
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);
// .....

function tick(event) {
    rock.alpha = 0.7;
    if (rock.hitTest(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY)) {//if hit, change alpha
        rock.alpha = 1;
    }
    var deltaS = event.delta / 1000;
    rock.x = (rock.x - deltaS * groundSpeed);//to gradually shift the rock
    if (rock.x + rock.image.width * rock.scaleX <= 0) {//to re-position the rock
        rock.x = w + Math.random() * 1000;
    }
    stage.update(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer when reading the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809123/animate-cc-html5-easeljs-stage-x-stage-y-mouse-position-not-consistent-between-c).

Rather than directly getting `stage.mouseX` or `stage.mouseY`, the correct position can be obtained using `globalToLocal` as on [this](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/HitTest/).

```
  var p = rock.globalToLocal(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);
  if (rock.hitTest(p.x, p.y)) {
      rock.alpha = 1;
  }
```