# EaselJS Drag Drop - With Drag Drop within Responsive Publish

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, responsive, easeljs, adobe-animate

**Software:** Adobe Animate
**Type:** HTML5 Canvas
**Publish Settings:** JavaScript/HTML (Loop Timeline | Include hidden layers | Center Stage: Both | Make Responsive: Both | Scale to visible area: Fit in view)

I've created a circle and converted it to a Movie Clip.
In frame one I've added the following Actions:

```
// Defines "circle" as the object named "circle" in the library.
var circle = this.addChild(new lib.circle());

circle.on("pressmove", function(evt) {
    evt.target.x = evt.stageX;
    evt.target.y = evt.stageY;
});
circle.on("pressup", function(evt) {
    console.log("up");
});
```

The problem appears when exporting to Responsive it seems the drag drop's offset. Does anyone know the reasoning behind this and a method to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because Animate's responsive export scales the stage. You may need to transform your coordinates.

[Check out this answer to an earlier post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809123/animate-cc-html5-easeljs-stage-x-stage-y-mouse-position-not-consistent-between-c/40819693#40819693)

Comment: Thanks for your help Lanny I'll try making those adjustments to my code and see how it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This works in Adobe Animate CC with responsive scaling.  Just replace yourMC with your movie clip.

```
this.yourMC.on("pressmove", function (evt) {
    var p = stage.globalToLocal(evt.stageX, evt.stageY);
    evt.currentTarget.x = p.x;
    evt.currentTarget.y = p.y;
});
```